# Open terminal in directory open in file explorer

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, command, nautilus

In GNOME, I wish to setup a shortcut to open terminal in presently viewing directory in the gui file explorer. The nautilus gui is opened from terminal by the command `xdg-open .`, but I'm not sure if I could manipulate this command to pipe the directory of the gui.

Comment: So you want to open a terminal window from the GUI file explorer nautilus, whereas the `pwd` in the newly opened terminal is the path your file explorer is currently showing? Like the possibility, which already exists in nautilus, to right-click a folder and choose `open in terminal`. But if you have a terminal running from which you open the GUI via `xdg-open .`, you already have a terminal window showing the wanted directory. Maybe I understand it wrong, since your description is a little bit short.

Comment: @lukeflo sorry for the confusion. I should have not used pwd here. What I meant was to open terminal in the present directory that the gui explorer is open in. I precisely want to avoid the right click route and want to enable a keyboard shortcut instead. Also if it matters, I use fedora 39.

Comment: Ok, I added a different solution which works on my OS. I'm running Manjaro Mate, but normally Desktop Environments like Gnome behave similar also on different distributions and Mate is a fork of Gnome, as is Mates file explorer Caja of Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Since OP wants to assing a single shortcut, maybe this will work:

Move to your `nautilus` config folder, normally `~/.config/nautilus`. There should be a file called `accels`. Open the file an search for a line containing something like:

`; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "")`

Remove the leading semicolon (which comments the line) and insert a shortcut at the end, e.g:

`(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "F2")`

Now restart `nautilus` (make sure it really quits with e.g. `nautilus -q`). After restart you should be able to open a terminal from the current directory by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>. At least, it works on my machine.

**Original answer**

You could try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> while nautilus is the active window (which is like right-click) and then press the button which is highlited in the pop-up menu for **open in terminal**. In my case, with German language settings, its `t/T`:

[image]

Credit: https://askubuntu.com/a/1213365

The quoted link to AskUbuntu provides some more examples how to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Unfortunately, I think this no longer works with the latest versions of nautilus as noted by the answers in the link as well. I created the file and added the new line and it doesnt work.

Comment: Then maybe try the script method: https://askubuntu.com/a/1079882/1771279 Seems to work also with newer versions of at least Ubuntu